# Manage "open at login" items programmatically from CLI

Tags: mac, command-line, startup, java

I'd like to control a Java (not swift / native) application startup during login. While I can add plists-s to user's LaunchAgents, this does not show up as a login item in system settings. How can I manage those entries programmatically (command line) ?